# Connection to IBM db2 in R fails - idaInit() error

Tags: r, db2, rodbc

I was recently forced to update R to the latest version of 4.1.2 and since then my connection to db2 is not working. I use ibmdbR. I follow the steps as recommended by IBM:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-warehouse?topic=science-r-development-environment

it fails at step d, nitialising the analytics package by issuing the following R command.
The ODBC connection works (or seems to be working) but idaInit(con) fails with the following error:

```
> idaInit(con)  #this fails
Error in assign("idaRGlobal", new.env(parent = baseenv()), envir = baseenv()) : 
cannot add binding of 'idaRGlobal' to the base environment
```

The con object is created without an issue:

`> con <- idaConnect(con.text) # this is successful and con is created`

I've tested my ODBC connection using online reference (below) and it's successful.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-warehouse?topic=programmatically-odbc-cli

More info on setup:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ibmdbR_1.50.0 arules_1.7-2  Matrix_1.4-0  RODBC_1.3-19 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_2.0.1   MASS_7.3-54      tidyselect_1.1.1 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_2.0-2 lattice_0.20-45  R6_2.5.1         rlang_0.4.12     fansi_0.5.0      dplyr_1.0.7     
[11] tools_4.1.2      parallel_4.1.2   grid_4.1.2       rpart.plot_3.1.0 gtable_0.3.0     utf8_1.2.2       ellipsis_0.3.2   tibble_3.1.6     lifecycle_1.0.1  crayon_1.4.2    
[21] purrr_0.3.4      ggplot2_3.3.5    vctrs_0.3.8      rpart_4.1-15     glue_1.5.1       compiler_4.1.2   pillar_1.6.4     generics_0.1.1   scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

It seems the error comes from executing this assignment in the code: `assign("idaRGlobal", new.env(parent = baseenv()), envir=baseenv())`

idaInit() code can be found here: [rdrr.io/cran/ibmdbR/src/R/connection.R](http://rdrr.io/cran/ibmdbR/src/R/connection.R)

I have completely removed R with all its libraries and installed everything from scratch, so I don't see how it could be a versioning issue. All packages seem to have the latest version. The only package that hasn't been updated after the release of R 4.2.1 are RODBC and IBMDBR.

---

Edit: Tried using RODBC directly and the connection works fine.

Comment: Which Db2-server are you using ( Db2-warehouse-on-cloud,  on-premises, Db2-for-Z/OS) ?

Comment: on prem, running on Windows Server 2016 Standard and Db2 v11.5 fix pack 0

Comment: This might be a known breaking change in r4.1 and the ibm idaInit() might need changing. Instead of `assign("idaRGlobal", new.env(parent = baseenv()), envir=baseenv())` try `assign("idaRGlobal", new.env(parent = baseenv()), envir=globalenv())`. Other workaround may exist.

Comment: Is your AS400 remote or on premise? Have you CCSID flag on or off in ODBC connection?

Comment: The solution of @mao is not fully working, does anyone know if that is the correct workaround for changes in R 4.1?